# Let $\epsilon > 0$ be any positive number. Some $a \in A$ with $a > x - \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, formal-proofs

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty set that is bounded above. Suppose that $x$ is the least upper bound for $A$. Now let $\epsilon > 0$ be any positive number. Explain why you know that there must be some $a ∈ A$ with $a > x - \epsilon$.

What I have so far: Since $\epsilon$ is greater than $0$ then I assume that $\epsilon > A \subset \mathbb{R}$. When we subtract the least upper boundaries or the min of the set from the $\max (\epsilon(x - \epsilon))$ you should get some value that is less than a so $x =$ least upper bound 
$\epsilon > 0$ 
$a \in A$ 
$A \subset \mathbb{R}$
$x - \epsilon > 0$ but $< a$ so $x - \epsilon < a$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: How is "$\varepsilon > A$" interpreted?  Do you have a meaning for comparing the value of a number to the value of a set?

Comment: Suppose there is no $a \in A$ such that $a > x - \varepsilon$.  Does this cause any trouble for the claim $a$ is the **least** upper bound of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

If there was no $a\in A$ such that $a>x-\varepsilon$ You have
$$x-\varepsilon\geq a$$ for all $a\in A$
and thus $x-\varepsilon$ would be an upper bound for $A$ contradicting that $x$ is the least upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that $x-\epsilon < x$.

The *definition* for $x$ being an upper bound of $A$ means (along with $x$ being an upper bound of $A$) is that anything *less* than $x$ is *not* an upper bound of $A$.

$x-\epsilon < x$ so $x-\epsilon$ is *not* an upper bound of $A$.

The *definition* of $y$ being an upper bound of $A$ is that $y$ is equal to or larger then any $a$ in $A$.  Since $x-\epsilon$ is *not* an upper bound of $A$ this is *not* true for $x-\epsilon$.

So it is *not* true that every $y$ is equal to or larger than any $a$ in $A$, there must be at least one $a \in A$ so that $x-\epsilon$ is smaller than $a$.